# HTTP_REFERER to location Iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, http-referer

First of all, my php knowledge is equal to zero.
But I've manage to find a script that check if the visitor is coming from a certain site and then redirects the visitor to another:

```
<?php 

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

if ($referer =   'http://www.facebook.com/') 
{ 
header('Location: http://www.test.com/facebook'); 
} 

else 
{ 
header('Location: http://www.test.com/failed'); 
} 

?>
```

But i was wondering If I can use this script on a page itself. So if a user is coming from i.e. Facebook he is directed to an iframe with content on the same page? Like "Location: iframe". Otherwise he's not allowed on the page and will get redirected.

Kind of like a gatekeeper ;)

Thanks in advance guys!

/a

Comment: Do understand that HTTP_REFERER is by no means 'secure'. This data can easily be spoofed, since it's just send in the headers of the request. (or not..). Some plugins for browsers will also remove referer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the redirect at the top of the page: This reads "If visitor did NOT come from facebook, redirect them. If they did, show rest of page

```
<?php 

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

if (strpos($referer, 'www.facebook.com') === FALSE)
{ 
    header('Location: http://www.test.com/failed'); 
    exit();
} 


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- etc etc -->
```

Please note that referer headers can be faked, and are not guaranteed to be sent at all, depending on how the users browser is configured

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
This is exactly what I want to do! Can't get it to work though :(
Should I put my HTML-content where it says //rest of page here? Within the <?php ?> tags?
Because in Dreamweaver it says syntax-error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a "else" somewhere? Just guessing?

Comment: @user3607481 No need for else, and no if the page is html, put it After the closing `?>` tag, see my edit

Comment: @user3607481 in case you are wondering, else is not required here because if the condition is true, the user is redirected so the rest of the script is not displayed. Its probably good practice to explicitly terminate the script with `exit();` though, as per edit.

Comment: Still sending users to the failed-page even if they come from facebook :( What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The referer might not be facebook.com, it might be facebook.com/some/page.php, so i changed the check to be less specific. However, if the user is visiting facebook via https then no referer will be sent. I dont know if facebook force https nowadays, not a current user

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION to check if he is authenticated to visit the site or not